# Semicolon before square bracket

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-2018

Can anyone tell me why yarn format is adding a semi colon before my square brackets. Yarn build fails without it..

```
    ;[
      this.querySelector('[class$="-cover"] img'),
      this.querySelector('.FullscreenCarousel-cover-count')
     ].forEach(item => {
         // actions
    })
    })
```

Comment: Is there anything before this?

Comment: you are probably embedding some other JS in front of this code, that does not properly terminate the last line with a semicolon.

Comment: Is there any chance we could see the rest of the code surrounding this? More context would be much appreciated

Comment: I have this within a function so the line before this starts as `handleFullscreen () { `

Comment: Sounds like i have syntax error somewhere in that case if this isn't part of the language

Comment: In fact, I'm not allowed terminate variables or functions with semi colons, one of the linting rules. When I search the code base, I have another instance of this being used;

`
 ;['append', 'delete', 'set'].forEach(function(methodName) {`

 It appears to be apart of the language when you do a foreach this way

Comment: If the line before a bracket isn't terminated with a semi-colon, then odds are the brackets will be read as a property/index accessor instead of an array. [Example](https://jsfiddle.net/pusvey1w/)

Comment: Makes total sense now, thanks so much Tyler

Comment: @PaulMackey *"In fact, I'm not allowed terminate variables or functions with semi colons, one of the linting rules"* - Side note: I have to wonder why in the world a linter would force you to write code this way.

Comment: Because you configured your linter [not to use semicolons at the end of your lines](http://inimino.org/~inimino/blog/javascript_semicolons), it forces you to put one at the beginning of each line where it is necessary to separate statements.

Comment: Btw, avoid it by simply writing `for (const item of […])` instead of putting array literals at the beginning of a line.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Consider the following (basic) code:

```
doSomething()
[1].forEach(i => doAnotherThing(i))
```

Reading it this way, it looks straightforward--call some function, and then iterate over an array and call another function. Two separate steps.

However, JS doesn't look at whitespace. What if you saw the code like this:

```
doSomething()[1].forEach(i => doAnotherThing(i))
```

What does that now mean? Now it looks like you need to call `doSomething()` which returns an array, take item 1 of that array, and hopefully *that* is an array because we are iterating over it.

As opposed to:

```
doSomething();[1].forEach(i => doAnotherThing(i))
```

Which also condenses the whitespace but now is clear that you mean these to be two completely separate steps. The primary reason for prepending with a semicolon like that is to clarify your intentions.

Comment: Ahhhh, very clever. So it's just stating 'yep, this is the start of a new process'. Nice, that clears things up. Thanks very much mherzig

Comment: @PaulMackey You can accept an answer by clicking the grey checkmark next to it. Doing so help others find better answers, as well as give some reputation to the answerer and you.

Answer (score 0):

```js
console.log('First line')
['a', 'b', 'c'].forEach((element) => console.log(element))
console.log('Third line')
```

- 1: `First line`, then print `a, b, c` in a new line, and finally print `Third line` as next line
- 2: `First line`, then print `a, b, c` in a first line, and  print `Third line` as next line
- 3:  Missing semi-colon error
- 4:  Cannot read properties of undefined

**Answer**

##### Answer: 4

When JavaScript encounters a line break without a semicolon, the JavaScript parser will automatically add a semicolon based on a set of rules called `Automatic Semicolon Insertion` which determines whether line break as end of statement or not to insert semicolon. But it does not assume a semicolon before square brackets [...]. So the first two lines considered as a single statement as below.

```js
console.log('First line')['a', 'b', 'c'].forEach((element) => console.log(element))
```

Hence, there will be **cannot read properties of undefined** error while applying the array square bracket on log function.